# How can we deploy a django application on aws if we are using wkhtmltopdf for pdfkit?

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit on windows to convert HTML URL to a pdf file and send it as a response. I installed wkhtmltopdf on my system, as it was a dependency to use pdfkit. I am adding the path for wkhtmtopdf stored in my drive, to the configuration value of pdfkit. Everything is working properly, but my concern is, the path is hardcoded in my app, now what happens if I want to dockerize my application and deploy it on amazon.
Here is the code that I am using:

```
            path_wkthmltopdf = 'C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
            config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkthmltopdf)
            pdf = pdfkit.from_url(order["invoice_url"], False, configuration=config)
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_" + order["order_id"] + "_" + datetime.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y') + ".pdf"
            content = "attachment; filename=" + filename
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
```

Is there a better way to handle this HTML URL to PDF conversion?

Comment: Copy the .exe to your project. A better way to do would be to do a wget+unzip in the docker config.(i.e commands for installation)

Comment: You mean, copy the .exe file of wkhtmltopdf in my project and then install it while dockerizing? That's good, but what about the configuration path that I have hardcoded in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the docker file to add wkhtml2pdf to your docker:

https://github.com/openlabs/docker-wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/Dockerfile

```
# Download and install wkhtmltopdf
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential xorg libssl-dev libxrender-dev wget gdebi
RUN wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wkhtmltopdf/0.12.2.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
RUN gdebi --n wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

Comment: Sure, but I have hardcoded the path to wkhtmltopdf for pdfkit configuration in my code. What changing would I have to do in my code?